# How do I display the selected tags in Select2 below the dropdown box?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 (version 4) with tags and would like to have the selected choices display below the input field.

So instead of:

[image: Standard choices]

Rather have:

[image]

Is this possible and if so how do I achieve that?

EDIT:
Code is:

```
<select class="js-example-tags form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">orange</option>
    <option selected="selected">white</option>
    <option selected="selected">purple</option>
    <option selected="selected">red</option>
    <option selected="selected">blue</option>
    <option selected="selected">green</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
tags: true
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your elements get rendered, a ul with a class is added for the elements. This class name is: `select2-selection__rendered`
So my idea was that after it was rendered, I could take this class and add some bottom. For this I used JQuery using `$(function()` note that what this does is to load after everything has loaded, so for the javascript code you need, is as follows (tested):

**Javascript code:**

```
  <script>
  $(".js-example-tags").select2({
   tags: true
  });

   $(function() {
      //Here you add the bottom pixels you need. I added 200px.
      $('.select2-selection__rendered').css({top:'200px',position:'relative'});
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: thank you, this is great and almost there for me..... one aspect on this is that if there are elements below the dropdown the display gets a bit confused with the selected tags being placed under the following elements. Is there a way to "auto-expand" the height of the added ul according to how many choices there are?

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mhluzi/q80ow33h/1/) to demonstrate what I meant in the comment above: 
Basically I would like to be able to place the results under each relevant dropdown.

Comment: is that better http://jsfiddle.net/q80ow33h/11/ you can add the height you need. @MhluziBhaka Hold on. I didn't test the dropdown, not working properly

Comment: this is not correct, if you click in the text box , the cursor is not in the correct place

Answer (score 18):

I came across this question a few weeks ago and wanted to share an alternative solution that I felt carried less risk than some of the style modifications to Select2 that other answers required.

What our team ended up using was a script that listened to the `change` event of the underlying `<select>` element to build/rebuild a styled unordered list in a sibling element:

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
    tags: true
}).on('change', function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var $container = $(this).siblings('.js-example-tags-container');

    var $list = $('<ul>');
    $selected.each(function(k, v) {
       var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">×</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
       $list.append($li);
    });
    $container.html('').append($list);
}).trigger('change');
```

And, to give the new list the functionality in addition to the appearance of the select2 tags, we listened for a `click` event and paired each list item with the corresponding `option` in the `<select>` so it could toggle the selected state and trigger the `change` event again:

```
$selected.each(function(k, v) {
    var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">×</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
    $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
        .off('click.select2-copy')
        .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
              var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');
              $opt.attr('selected', false);
              $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
        }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
    $list.append($li);
});
```

After this, it was a matter of using `display: none` to hide the `.select2-selection__choice` elements.

Note in jQuery version > 3 set property instead of attribute `$opt.prop('selected', false)` in other case it will not remove created tags;

The full example is available for review here: http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/ybneqdqa/ -- hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I have tried to apply this example but it is not working for me. can you please check. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626836/jquery-select2-ajax-search-select-multiple

Comment: updated url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702152/jquery-select2-ajax-search-display-selected-results-in-another-div

Comment: The example works great 
If you see select container is completely blank what if i want to display place holder there?

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried to use this code with some alterations to styling, but removing (pressing "X") it actually has no effect. I believe this is because no ID is being set on each select option. https://codepen.io/ftahir192/pen/paeYzV This codepen demonstrates the problem. Wondering if anybody else has run into this issue and knows of a fix?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same need, so I wrote a [custom selection adapter](https://github.com/andreivictor/select2-customSelectionAdapter) that will work for **Select2 v4**.

---

### What are Select2 Adapters?

According to [docs](https://select2.org/advanced/adapters-and-decorators), Select2 uses the Adapter pattern, so the recommended way to extend its functionality is by implementing our own adapters.

The `SelectionAdapter` controls the display of the selection option(s), as well anything else that needs to be embedded within the container, such as a search box.

Select2 provides the `SingleSelection` and `MultipleSelection` adapters as default implementations of the SelectionAdapter for single and multi-select controls, respectively.

The selection adapter can be overridden by assigning a custom adapter to the `selectionAdapter` configuration option.

---

### Select2 with custom Selection Adapter

The full code of the [plugin](https://github.com/andreivictor/select2-customSelectionAdapter) is too big to post it here. It has only 3kb minified.
You have to include it after Select2 main javascript file:

```
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script src="select2.customSelectionAdapter.min.js"></script>
```

And the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2.customSelectionAdapter.css" />
```

Then, initialise the plugin as follows:

```
var CustomSelectionAdapter = $.fn.select2.amd.require("select2/selection/customSelectionAdapter");

$("select").select2({
    // other options 
    selectionAdapter: CustomSelectionAdapter
});
```

By default, the tags are added immediately after the select2 container. You can use the `selectionContainer` option to add them somewhere else in the page:

```
$("select").select2({
    // other options 
    selectionAdapter: CustomSelectionAdapter,
    selectionContainer: $('.foo')
});
```

---

### Demo

https://andreivictor.github.io/select2-customSelectionAdapter/

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to comment on the selected answer... but what about the cases where you have multiple select2s on the page and only want to do this to one.  is there any reliable way to identify that one vs all of them?

Comment: You could try :

    $('#2 .select2-selection__rendered').css({top:'100px',position:'relative'});
    $('#2 .select2-container').append("<div style='height:100px'></div>");



Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q80ow33h/12/

Comment: Just for clarity, in the answer above the #2 is the id of your specific select2

Comment: The issue I was having was that if you select "multiple" the rendered Select2 isn't actually given an ID.  I ended up having to use the .next() jQuery function and assume (yikes) that the select2 would always be the control right after the original `select`. Then i generated and set an ID on each Select2, based on the ID of the `select`.

Raised an issue regarding it as well on the git:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3447

Comment: You can give your selections container an additional class as per the docs, so you could target your css style to the select2 selections that are children of this specific class selector.