# Select2, display tags into another DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I Would like display tags from a select2 form into another DIV. I tried the solution proposed by TJ Nicolaides https://stackoverflow.com/a/34140018/3030970 but it does not work on jQuery > 3 when you remove a tag, then add it again, you can not remove it any more

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
}).on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  var $container = $(this).siblings('.js-example-tags-container');

  var $list = $('<ul>');
  $selected.each(function(k, v) {
    var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">×</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
    $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
      .off('click.select2-copy')
      .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
        var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');
        $opt.attr('selected', false);
        $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
      }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
    $list.append($li);
  });
  $container.html('').append($list);
}).trigger('change');
```

The fiddle proposed by TJ Nicolaides : http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/ybneqdqa/

Is the problem related to the data() method?

Thx for your help :)

Comment: Using th fiddle linked It's working for me using 3.2.1 and 3.1.1 what error is showing to you in your console?

Comment: Nothing in the console, but when you remove a tag, then add it again, you can not remove it any more

Comment: You should add that to your question. As It doesn't work is not that of descriptive problem

Comment: Sure, you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, it was not relative to the `data()` method but to the `attr()` method used to set the selected value to false.

I simply replace `attr()` by `prop()` method, more adapted to this context.

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
}).on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  var $container = $(this).siblings('.js-example-tags-container');

  var $list = $('<ul>');
  $selected.each(function(k, v) {
    var $li = $('<li class="tag-selected"><a class="destroy-tag-selected">×</a>' + $(v).text() + '</li>');
    $li.children('a.destroy-tag-selected')
      .off('click.select2-copy')
      .on('click.select2-copy', function(e) {
        var $opt = $(this).data('select2-opt');

        $opt.prop('selected', false); // <-- Main difference

        $opt.parents('select').trigger('change');
      }).data('select2-opt', $(v));
    $list.append($li);
  });
  $container.html('').append($list);
}).trigger('change');
```